# how to get set font of text with another text's font

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I have two Text items in qml and I want to set font of first text to the font of second text. How can I do that?

e.g

```
Text{
  id:t1
  //some code
  //anchors ..etc
}

Text{
  //set font = t1.font or something similar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you need to use colon `:` to assign the property:

```
Text {
   id: txt1
   font.bold: true
   text: "Hello"
}

Text {
   id: txt2
   font: txt1.font
   text: "World"
}
```